# Cocoa Scrolling Image Menu

Tags: macos, cocoa, menu, scroll, objective-c-2.0

I want to make a menu with a wide image that scrolls horizontally (it's a continuous image). What technique could I use for this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to do this is to create a `NSScrollView` and nest a `NSImage` in it. You could run into problems if your continuous image is too large, however. In that case you'd want to split it into multiple `NSImage`s and arrange them next to each other in the `NSScrollView`.

Comment: Okay thanks! What's too large, you think? And how do I animate the scrolling?

Comment: Oh, do you want the image to scroll by itself and ignore user input? In that case, you can get rid of the `UIScrollView` and instead use `UIAnimation` to adjust the position of the `UIImageView` (or `UIImageviews`) over time. Many older iOS devices won't allow an image larger than 1024 pixels in width or height; newer devices have limits of 2048 pixels.

Comment: Oh yes and I'm on osx not on iOS! I'll edit the tags, sorry! But what you say must be somewhat similar to the solution on osx, no?

Comment: Yes, you'll probably just need to replace all occurrences of `UI` with `NS` :) And it's likely that you won't have any trouble with larger images.

Comment: Okay I'll document myself and answer my own question when I find a solution, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!